# Timeouts when indexing

Tags: elasticsearch

I am getting timeouts when attempting to index ~825,000 documents.  I am using the python client and set the timeout parameter of the index function to 5 seconds.  This has started happening since I recently went from one node to a cluster of 3 nodes.  It appears that right around the time that I get the timeout, Marvel is showing a "shard_started" event.  Is there any way that I can avoid these timeouts?